# Convexity/concavity of a strictly increasing and continuous function

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis

Consider a continuous, strictly increasing function $f:\mathbb{R}_{+}\to \mathbb{R}_{+}$ with

- $f(0)=0$, and
- $x>f(x)$ for all $x>0$.

Is this enough to conclude anything about convexity/concavity in the neighborhood of 0? In other words,

- Is there an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $f$ is convex or concave on $[0,\varepsilon]$?
- If not, what would a counterexample look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not enough.

Consider this example. Partition $(0,1]$ into $\cup_{n=0}^\infty (2^{-n-1},2^{-n}]$. For even $n$, let $f$ be the line segment connecting $(2^{-n-1},2^{-n-2})$ and $(2^{-n},2^{-n-1})$ on the interval $(2^{-n-1},2^{-n}]$. For odd $n$, let $f$ be the line segment connecting $(2^{-n-1},2^{-n-1})$ and $(2^{-n},2^{-n-1})$ on the interval $(2^{-n-1},2^{-n}].$ Finally $f(0)=0$.

If you draw a graph, it is straightforward to see $f$ is neither concave nor convex in any neighborhood of $0$.

Finally $f$ satisfies all the conditions you required except strict monotonicity because $f$ is flat on each $(2^{-n-1},2^{-n}]$ when $n$ is odd. But this is easy to resolve by modifying its slope a little bit.

Comment: Thank you very much! Do you perhaps have any suggestions regarding additional conditions or constraints that would exclude such pathological functions?

Comment: Sorry I don't know. I think monotonicity is not related to convexity/concavity.